# Post method issue

Tags: php, post

I have displayed a table and in each of its row i have added a rate button.  it needs to pick the first column of the row which is $objresult[0] and send it to other page(rate.php)
 but when i send it  on the other page with method post it just posts "$objresult[0]" this. instead of the value of of the column. I have tried to put it in php script. as you can see. cause it is a php object. and even out of php script.  but both ways.. it is just printing "$objresult[0]". Can you see please

```html
<tr>  
<td><?=$objResult["0"];?></td>  
<td><?=$objResult["1"];?></td>  
<td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["2"];?></div></td>  
<td align="right"><?=$objResult["3"];?></td>  
<td align="right"><?=$objResult["4"];?></td>  
 <td><?<form action='rate.php' method='POST'> <input type='hidden' name='name' value<?php= '$objResult["0"];' ?> >
                                  <input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Rate'/></form></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
<input type='hidden' name='name' value<?php= '$objResult["0"];' ?> >
```

Should be:

```
<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo $objResult["0"]; ?>' />
```

You're missing the equal sign, and you have the single quotes in the wrong place.

EDIT:  You have an extraneous `<?` before `<form` that you need to get rid of.

```
 <td><?<form
```

What is that there for?  It won't do anything but cause an error.

Comment: i have  replaced my code as asked by you. Now even button press do not directs me to rate .php. Kindly help

Comment: @Mani, No, I caught what it is. See my edit.

Comment: in the row  the first column is $objResult["0"]   and the value there is  ariel   name of a product.

Comment: Thanks much. It is much needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of issues.

**1.** Your short tag echos don't need the ";" at the the end.

**2.** Make sure php.ini has short tags turned on. I believe they're off by default.

Answer (score 0):

change php.ini configuration to use short open tag in php, your code using `<?=` instead using `<?php echo`, just enabled the shortopen tag in your php configuration file

Comment: i have changed my php tages to <?php  ?> now i ma not with one more problem that i am unable to go to rate.php. kindly help please

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the PHP version running on your server wasn't configured for using [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

So instead of using `<?=` try using `<?php`.

Comment: double vs single quotes is totally irrelevant; both work fine.

Comment: the '<?=' 'short tag' is available everywhere and is recommended  to be used rather than '<?php echo' in the later PHP versions.

Comment: I  now used  <?php  ?>  these  still pressing buton do not directs me to the rate.php page :(

Comment: were are the input names?

Comment: this is my edited line as asked
 <input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo $objResult["0"]; ?>'/>
and here is the post line of rate.php page..  in $name i want the value
$name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: The action is not being called. Use <td> <form action='rate.php' method='POST'> <input type='hidden' name='name' value<?php echo '$objResult["0"];' ?> >

Comment: How are u creating the $objResult?

Comment: hey!!! i got the solution....  thanks to @developerwjk look at his edited solution above :) thank you as well  much needed :)